# Check if GLUT has been initialized?

Tags: opengl, glut

Does GLUT provide some user-accessible mechanism to check whether glutInit has been called? I'm debugging some issues in an existing app and this would be a really helpful debugging tool!

Comment: Are you calling GLUT? If so, use a global flag that is set when you call the GLUT init. Now you can simply test that flag. But why use GLUT when there is freeglut? And why use freeglut when there is glfw? Much better.

Comment: @Lars Pensjö: there are many introductory samples using glut. 'Porting' to GLFW would be time consuming, distracting and useless. And I found myself that full screen mode of freeglut was working better than GLFW, using Horde3d.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `glutGet` with the `GLUT_INIT_STATE` parameter:

```
bool glutInitialised = glutGet(GLUT_INIT_STATE) == 1;
```

Comment: True, but it's unclear from the question whether it just means original GLUT, and I can't think of a reason why FreeGLUT wouldn't be used over the original GLUT.

Comment: GLUT_INIT_STATE is not defined on Ubuntu